# CodeIgniter 2, DataMapper Validation Rules

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm using CodeIgniter 2 with [DataMapper ORM](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/).
For Users, I have `confirm_password` and `confirm_email` fields (plus others) which both aren't fields in the database (table `users` does not have these fields), but it's just there to show on the sign-up form:

I also have back-end where these 2 fields (`confirm_password` and `confirm_email`) do not exist in the form.

```
public $validation = array(
'first_name' => array(
    'label' => 'lang:common_first_name',
    'rules' => array('required', 'trim')
),
'last_name' => array(
    'label' => 'lang:common_last_name',
    'rules' => array('trim')
),
'email' => array(
    'label' => 'lang:common_email',
    'rules' => array('required', 'trim', 'unique', 'valid_email')
),
'confirm_email' => array(
    'label' => 'lang:common_confirm_email',
    'rules' => array('matches' => 'email')
),
'password' => array(
    'label' => 'lang:common_password',
    'rules' => array('required', 'min_length' => 6, 'encrypt')
),
'confirm_password' => array(
    'label' => 'lang:common_confirm_password',
    'rules' => array('matches' => 'password')
)
```

);

If I don't make the `confirm_email` or `confirm_email` fields **required**, the validator won't trigger the **matches** rule.
If I make them **required**, then the back-end that does not have these fields, triggers the `confirm_email` and `confirm_password`, but it shouldn't.

- Is it best to include ALL possible validation rules (in the model of course) that we may have in the application?
- Is it a good idea to alter these rules in the controller (say remove
  `confirm_email` index from `$validation` array) when adding user on
  back-end?

I appreciate any thoughts.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest version of ORM Mapper, according to documentation you can add non database fields.

http://stensi.com/datamapper/pages/validation.html

> Also, you can now add validation rules for non-Database Table fields,
>   such as 'Confirm Email Address' or 'Confirm Password'. For example:

and you don't need **required** rule for the confirmation fields - as they indicate that filed is required in DB hence the DB error) ,  - the **matches** property will do the *required* validation against the matched field (e.g. if it dosen't match it will throw the error.) In other words  you only need required on 'email' field, confirmation_email will throw the error if filed don't match. On empty field you really need to show that email is required.

Finally - you can remove the index, but generally thats not good idea. I would , instead, if above fails -  add the form validation rule in controller.